# SEO friendly approach for jQuery.i18n

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, internationalization

I'm trying to add support for at least two languages on a website. I have been looking at jQuery.i18n so far.

This tutorial provides great instructions on how the project should be set up:

https://blog.lokalise.co/localizing-apps-jquery/

On the back end, I am running a NodeJS server, but for now with no useful back end logic. The only thing I'm doing here is serving my static HTML files.

I was wondering if this is an SEO friendly approach to create a multilingual website? If not, would it make more sense to translate all my content through some back end logic?

Thanks in advance.